# Autohotkey, toggle boolean variable not work properly

Tags: boolean, autohotkey

I've written an Autohotkey program to toggle zoom in level of Windows built-in magnifier. It's very simple. When you move your mouse to the top left corner, it zooms in, and it zooms out next time you move to the top left corner. Below is my code. The problem is that it always zooms in. I don't know where is the problem. Can anyone help to take a look?

```
; Timer to check mouse position
SetTimer, CheckMouse, 300

#Persistent
#SingleInstance force

WinGetPos,,,Xmax,Ymax,ahk_class Progman  ; get desktop size

T = 4   ; adjust tolerance value if desired

Xmax := Xmax - T   ; allow tolerance to mouse corner activation position
Ymax := Ymax - T

CheckMouse:                   ; check mouse position
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY

GetKeyState, SState, Shift
GetKeyState, AState, Alt
GetKeyState, CState, Control

zoom_toggle := True

if (MouseY < T and MouseX < T and CState = "U" and AState = "U" and SState = "U")
{
    if(zoom_toggle)
    {
        Send #{+}
        zoom_toggle := False
    }
    else
    {
        Send #{-}
        zoom_toggle := True
    }
}

Return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things to fix/improve.
I'll start off with the actual problem, and then go over stuff you should/could improve.

So the actual problem, every time you run you timer, you set the `zoom_toggle` variable to be `true`. So yeah, not much help trying to do any toggles when the value is reset every time.
Move the definition to be at the top of the script, or due to how forgiving ahk is, you could actually entirely skip declaring the variable. That way when it's first used, it's created with the default value of *nothing*, which evaluates to `false`.

And now onto other fixes/improvements.
Location of your #directives.
Good/common practice is defining these types of #directives at the very top of your script.

Usage of `WinGetPos` to get screen width/height.
You could use the [`A_ScreenWidth`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Screen) and [`A_ScreenHeight`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Screen) variables to easily get your screen width and height.

Missing [`return`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Return.htm) that should end your [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto).
When you launch the script for the very first time, there is nothing that stops the code execution from falling through all the way to your timer's callback label.
Nothing bad will result of this in your case, but for future reference, you don't want this to happen. Use a `return` to stop code execution and end the auto-execute section.

Redundant code
There is no need to set `CoordMode` every time you run the timer. Move this command to be at the top of your script.
In your send command, there is no need to wrap `-` inside `{ }`. That is only done to escape characters that have special meaning in a send command, and `-` has none. In special cases you may even encounter unwanted behavior by doing this. More about this in the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm).
Why are `Xmax` and `Ymax` being created? They're doing nothing for us?

Usage of [`Send`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Send_variants) instead of [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail)
`SendInput` is faster and more reliable. Should almost always be used over `Send`.
You can specify [`SendMode, Input`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendMode.htm) at the top of your script to turn all `Send` commands into `SendInput`. Personally I prefer just writing out `SendInput`.

Legacy code
Technically nothing wrong with using legacy code, but it's definitely not recommended.
Compatibility with future AHK versions is non-existent as well. Expression syntax is what should always be used nowadays.
Use the function [`GetKeyState()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm) instead of the legacy command.
Use the non-legacy [operators](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#operators) (`&&`, `||`, etc) instead of legacy `AND`, `OR`, etc.
Always use `:=` instead of `=`. Legacy assignment is never used.
Usage of a label is pretty much legacy as well. Should replace with a function, but then I should ensure you understand function scopes as well. If you want, I can.

Here's your revised code:

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance, Force
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen ;move this to the top, needs to be executed only once

; Timer to check mouse position
SetTimer, CheckMouse, 1000

T := 4   ; adjust tolerance value if desired
Xmax := A_ScreenWidth - T   ; allow tolerance to mouse corner activation position
Ymax := A_ScreenHeight - T
;not sure why we're creating these two variables though, they're doing absolutely nothing for us?

return ;end auto-execute section

CheckMouse:                   ; check mouse position
    MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
    SState := GetKeyState("Shift", "P")
    AState := GetKeyState("Alt", "P")
    CState := GetKeyState("Control", "P") 
    ;returns true/false (1/0)
    ;true meaning the key is down

    if (MouseY < T && MouseX < T && !SState && !AState && !CState)
    {
        ;I skipped definin the zoom_toggle variable so it's created for us
        ;with the default value of nothing, which evaluates to false
        ;had to flip around the if statement to account for this as well
        if(!zoom_toggle) 
        {
            SendInput, #{+}
            zoom_toggle := true
        }
        else
        {
            SendInput, #-
            zoom_toggle := false
        }
    }
return ;ends the label
```

To ends off things, I'd like to say this isn't a very good implementation though. To make it at least usable, change the timer to run slower. I made it 1sec in that revised code.
If you want to make it better, a super simple way I could mention, is make it run code only once while the mouse is in that region. Adding another toggle for whether the mouse has exited that region would do it.
Also if you were to have a second monitor that's on the left of your main monitor in Windows, things would get pretty bad haha.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer! I learned a lot just by this answer. If you have spare time, could you also describe function scope? I'd like to know that as well. Thanks again!

Comment: I actually have a pretty good post about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59972282/3813732). Give it a read. And to turn your label `CheckMouse` into a function, all you need to do, is replace `CheckMouse:` with `CheckMouse()` + brackets like a function normally has.