# Why doesn't timer treat global variable correctly?

Tags: autohotkey

This continuously sends `t`:

```js
myVar := true

SetTimer, myLoop, 0

myLoop(){
    if (true) {
      Send, {t down}
    }
}

#Persistent
```

But this does nothing:

```js
myVar := true

SetTimer, myLoop, 0

myLoop(){
    if (myVar) {
      Send, {t down}
    }
}

#Persistent
```

Why?  `myVar` and `true` both evaluate to `true` so I don't understand why it's different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myVar := true` should be:

```cpp
global myVar := true
```

Because a `global` must explicitly be declared as such.

Comment: Why is this the case?

Comment: Globals have to be explicitly declared as such.

Comment: You're not declaring a global variable with this, you're declaring a [super-global](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#SuperGlobal) variable, which is bad practice and should only be used due to convenience in some quick small unimportant scripts. Read about the usage of a global variable from the documentation [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#Global). If you want to look at a longer text explanation, I have an older post about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59971340/how-can-my-autohotkey-script-launch-batch-scripts-accordingly/59972282#59972282).