# How to make it so you could change the hotkey in the GUI? - AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Code:

```
Gui, Add, Text,, ------------------------------------------Key Delay------------------------------------------
Gui, Add, Edit, w300 vKeyDelay, 100
Gui, Add, Text,, ------------------------------------------Key Input------------------------------------------
Gui, Add, Edit, R10 w300 vKeyPlayer
Gui, Add, Text,, ------------------------------------------Key Start------------------------------------------
Gui, Add, Edit, w300 vStartKey, F2
Gui, Show
F2::
!F2::
Gui, Submit, Nohide
SetKeyDelay, %KeyDelay%
Send, %KeyPlayer%
return
GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

The start key is set to F2, i want to make it so people are able to change it to whatever, (F1, F2, F3, A, B, C, 1-10, etc)

How to make it so you could change the hotkey in the gui?

Answer (score 0):

You'd use the [`Hotkey`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) command to create a hotkey during runtime.
And to choose the hotkey in the gui, the easiest (but not best) option would be the [hotkey control](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#Hotkey).
It's surely the easiest one that's also convenient for the end user, but it doesn't support anything beyond just regular hotkeys. For better approaches, you'd need a custom one.

[This](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/5288-custom-hotkey-control/) was the first custom one I found with a Google search. Haven't used it myself, but it might be good stuff.
A very easy, but powerful, custom one you could also use is just a [`Edit`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#Edit) control. Works very well if you expect your end users to be smart enough to type stuff like `!F1`, `+#k`, `d & o`, or whatever.

---

Anyway, I'll demonstrate here the usage of the built in hotkey control. Stop reading now if you want to figure it out yourself.

First, create the gui and associate a variable and a [g-label](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#label) to the hotkey control.
Though, I'm going to use a function instead of a [label](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Labels.htm), I don't like writing legacy AHK.

```
Gui, Add, Hotkey, % "x50 y25 w90 h30 vChosenHotkey gHotkeyChanged"
Gui, Show, % "w200 h100"
Return
```

Then the g-label `HotkeyChanged` needs to be defined, and I'll use a function instead of a label, as said above.

```
HotkeyChanged()
{
    global ChosenHotkey
    
    Gui, Submit, NoHide
    Hotkey, % ChosenHotkey, MyHotkey, On
}
```

And when using a function, you have to worry about scopes, which is why `global ChosenHotkey` is specified.
There I'm telling the function that I'll use a variable defined outside of its scope.
If scopes are something you don't yet know of, and don't yet want to to learn about them, you can write legacy AHK and use a label and forget about all this.
To learn about scopes in programming in general, you can probably find something good from Google.
And to learn about them in AHK specifically, I have a previous answer about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59971340/how-can-my-autohotkey-script-launch-batch-scripts-accordingly/59972282#59972282) and [here's](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm) the relevant documentation page.

Then I get the make the script update its associated variables with [`Gui, Submit`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Submit), you already seem to know about this.
And then I get to the [`Hotkey`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) command.
First parameter takes the hotkey to use, that's stored in the `ChosenHotkey` variable.
Second parameter a label/function name, or a function object. I'll use a function name `MyHotkey`.
And in the third parameter `On` is specified to turn the hotkey on and possibly replace any previous any previous hotkey that was in its place.

Then the function or label `MyHotkey` needs to be defined:

```
MyHotkey()
{
    MsgBox, % "Hotkey pressed!"
}
```

And that's it.
If you want to save the previously used hotkey and then use it again when the script is restarted, there are many options all of which basically just boil down the idea of saving the hotkey to some file.

---

Here's the full script:

```
Gui, Add, Hotkey, % "x50 y25 w90 h30 vChosenHotkey gHotkeyChanged"
Gui, Show, % "w200 h100"
return

HotkeyChanged()
{
    global ChosenHotkey
    
    Gui, Submit, NoHide
    Hotkey, % ChosenHotkey, MyHotkey, On
}

MyHotkey()
{
    MsgBox, % "Hotkey pressed!"
}

GuiClose()
{
    ExitApp
}
```

Comment: I tried using the script given, i integrated it to my own project, the one problem i noticed is that all the previous hotkey sets (F1, F2, F3,) and current being F4, Those old keys still act like an active hotkey, when only F4 is meant to work, i'm quite new to this stuff, count me as a newbie, i'm still figuring stuff out..

Comment: Could you show the code? Maybe edit it into your OP.