# Notify when clipboard change to something new

Tags: autohotkey

I want to show messagebox when my clipboard is different, than previous one. This is what I've managed:

```
#Persistent
OnClipboardChange("ClipChanged")
return

lastClipboardContent := ""

ClipChanged(Type) {
    if lastClipboardContent != Clipboard
    {
        lastClipboardContent := Clipboard
        MsgBox changed
    }
}
```

It actually shows messagebox every time my clipboard change, even, if the content is same as previous. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem is that your line of code `lastClipboardContent := ""` is never even reached, so it's doing literally nothing.
Though, even if it was reached, it would also do nothing of use for your script, which is where we get to the second issue, variable scopes.

Inside that function, any variable exists only for the duration of that function's lifespan (unless otherwise specified).
Since you want the variable to retain its value every time you call the function, you're going to want to define it as [static](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#static).
Global or super global would work as well, but I wouldn't recommend them for this, and they're not meant for this anyway.
An other person had the some problem as you're having, I wrote a more in-depth answer about this, which you can read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59971340/how-can-my-autohotkey-script-launch-batch-scripts-accordingly/59972282#59972282) if you're interested.

So here's the revised version:

```
#Persistent
OnClipboardChange("ClipChanged")
return

ClipChanged() 
{
    static lastClipboardContent
    if (lastClipboardContent != Clipboard)
    {
        ToolTip, % lastClipboardContent " changed to " Clipboard 
        lastClipboardContent := Clipboard
    }
}
```